Problem verifying safe signature (is valid)
We are developing a dapp and at some point of the flow we need to verify the user wallet ownership. For this we ask the user to sign a custom message and then we verify it recovering the signature like this.
    const recoveredAddress = await this.web3.eth.accounts.recover(
      message,
      signature,
    );

The problem is when this wallet is not a hot wallet but a multisign, and thus when doing the same flow for a safe sign it fails with this error recovery id invalid.
We then tried ton build a fallback to verify safe multisig with this code block. But unfortunately it always returns isValid false
import Safe, { hashSafeMessage } from '@safe-global/protocol-kit'

const validateSafeSign = async(MESSAGE, signature) => {
  const protocolKit = await Safe.default.init({
    provider: "https://ethereum-holesky-rpc.publicnode.com",
    // signer,
    // predictedSafe
  })

  const messageHash = hashSafeMessage(MESSAGE)

  const isValid = await protocolKit.isValidSignature(
    messageHash,
    signature)

  console.log({isValid})
}


validateSafeSign("Login request for address: 0x207e4bb824c7a8d998a0543f31fa0c1d56efc0ab. Nonce: 3821057a5b61b81caa14bbed5a5828eb", "0x6a3ebdab17e6f1bcacc13a2354854a7b1d3e5d8a9df4af32be1673ed89a830ab3ac28a7342550433946a8240e33193eea7073e925de3c2c9d2b793abd1f55a131c")

The arguments of MESSAGE and SIGNATURE provided are obtained from here
https://holesky-safe.protofire.io/transactions/messages?safe=holesky:0x207E4Bb824c7a8D998a0543f31Fa0c1d56eFc0aB
Any help or workaround on how can we verify if the signature is valid?
Thanks

We just found a working solution of the problem, i will share the code.
import Safe, { hashSafeMessage } from '@safe-global/protocol-kit';

  async validateSafeSignature(
    safeAddress: string,
    message: string,
    signature: string,
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    const protocolKit = await Safe.init({
      provider: this.rpcEndpoint,
      safeAddress,
    });

    const messageHash = hashSafeMessage(message);

    const isValid = await protocolKit.isValidSignature(messageHash, signature);

    return isValid;
  }

with the sdk and:

safeAddress safe address
message original plain text message
signature fullsig from safe

we were able to validate the signature
Thanks!

You can find a detailed guide to handle this case in Safe documentation. You will need to use the Protocol kit to create and submit a message, which will need to be approved by the owners. If the Safe only requires 1 owner, then the signature can be done right away with the user’s connected wallet; if not, your app will need to wait for all the required owners to sign the message in order to continue.
Please let me know if that answered your question 
Best, Louis

Thanks, but that's not the implementation flow we were looking for.
It was just a connection from our dApp with the Web3Modal package and linking with WalletConnect and Safe. We cannot control or modify the actions in the middle.
The problem was that we were not finding a way to validate the Safe signature with the message.
But look at the next answer, where I will post how we solved this.
